# Ayuda con clausula Where en MySQL y PHP para android

Tags: java, php, android, sql

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para Android y necesito hacer una consulta en sql usando php pero no sé por qué no me devuelve nada cuando hago la consulta. 
Éste es un código java para Android:

```
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    final String url="http://pear-web.com/profe.php";
    RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
    Aplicacion app = (Aplicacion) getApplicationContext();

    requestParams.add("login",app.getUsuario());
    client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if(statusCode==200)
            {
                progresDialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(responseBody));
                    for (i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                            Name.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Login"));
                            System.out.println(Name);
                            Apellido.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("apellido"));
                            Correo_profe.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Correo_padre"));
                            ID.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ID_profe"));


                    }
                    listView.setAdapter(new ImagenAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }`
```

Y éste es el código php:

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost="";
$database_localhost="";
$username_localhost="";
$password_localhost="";
$login = $_REQUEST["login"];
$localhost=mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,
$password_local    host)or die ("cannot conect");
mysql_select_db($database_localhost) or die("cannot selet DB");
$sql="SELECT Login,apellido,Correo_padre,ID_profe FROM usuario
WHERE ID_profe=$login ";  <---este es el where que menciono
$result = mysql_query($sql,$localhost);
$json = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
   while ($row=mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
       $json[]=$row;
    }
}
mysql_close($localhost);
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Cabe mencionar que cuando no le pongo el `Where` me muestra la consulta, pero quiero filtrar la lista cuando sea necesario. Ya lo intenté todo y no sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 1):

Definitivamente el problema es que el valor de `$login` no esta representado correctamente dentro del Query, si lo agregas como describes en tu pregunta, el valor de `$login` es simplemente un string que se agrega al Query:

```
$sql="SELECT Login,apellido,Correo_padre,ID_profe FROM usuario
WHERE ID_profe=$login ";
```

Debes agregar comillas simples para que el valor de la variable `$login` pueda representarse correctamente en el query:

```
$sql="SELECT Login,apellido,Correo_padre,ID_profe FROM usuario
WHERE ID_profe='$login'";
```

---

Este es un ejemplo de un Query:

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM TABLA_USUARIOS where usuario='$username' 
          and password='$password'");
```

Al poner entre comillas simples `'$username'`  y `'$password'`, el valor de estas variables se representara correctamente en el Query.

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado a ver si te coge bien el valor de las variables al recogerlas antes de realizar la consulta?

```
$login = $_REQUEST["login"];
echo $login;
```

Answer (score 0):

Añade comillas simples  ' ' en las variables que uses dentro de una consulta:

```
 $sql="SELECT Login,apellido,Correo_padre,ID_profe FROM usuario
    WHERE ID_profe='$login'";
```